# Unexpected behavior of open() in python library when run as task

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have custom python library installed on my NAS which has this code:

```
    try:
        i = open("/volume1/web/python/session.txt")
        try:
            a = str(i.read())
        except Exception as err:
            a = "Exception: {0}".format(err)
        finally:
            i.close()
    except Exception as err:
        a = "Exception: {0}".format(err)
    return a
```

This code is invoked by *app.py* which saves returned text to file.

When *app.py* is run from SSH, it saves the content of *session.txt* as intended.
**But** when *app.py* is run as task (*run.sh*), it saves exception *"'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)"*. Yeah, the file contains "á" in position 12, so I add *encoding="utf-8"* to open() function. And **this fails** (does not save anything, so I don't even know if and what error it threw.)

---

### QUESTION

Any ideas how to safely open and read text file by python library (when by regular script, runs correctly even if it is run as task)?

---

### FILES involved

**library**:

```
class API():
    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.DIR = dir

    def CheckTokens(self):
        print("\nChecking all saved tokens")

        try:
            i = open(os.path.join(self.DIR, "session.txt"), encoding='utf-8')
            try:
                a = i.read()
            except Exception as err:
                a = "Exception: {0}".format(err)
            finally:
                i.close()
        except Exception as err:
            a = "Exception: {0}".format(err)
        return a
```

**app.py**:

```
import os.path
from time import localtime, strftime
from APIfile import API

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LOCAL_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    def write(text, type):
        time = localtime()
        time = "%s@%s" % (strftime("%Y%m%d", time), strftime("%H%M%S", time))
        filename = "%s%s.txt" % (time, ("_%s" % type if type != "JSON" else ""))
        f = open(os.path.join(LOCAL_DIR, "logs", filename), "a")
        f.write(str(text))
        f.close()

    INSTANCE = API(LOCAL_DIR)
    tokens = INSTANCE.CheckTokens()
    write(tokens, "DEBUG")
```

**run.sh**:

```
python3 /volume1/web/python/app.py
```

**session.txt** and **logs** folder is located in the same directory as *app.py*

---

### OUTCOMES

1. Run from SSH *python3 /volume1/web/python/app.py* -> saves content of session.txt to log file
2. Run from SSH /volume1/web/python/run.sh -> does the same as *1.*
3. Run *run.sh* file as task (something like cron job) -> does not create log file
4. When I remove encoding='utf-8' statement from open function, in SSH run correctly, in task throws an exception *('ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128))*

Comment: Are you sure that SSH is using python3 rather than python 2.7?

Comment: 100% sure, I don't even have python 2.7 installed ;) BTW, would that change anything?

Comment: So `python3 /your/path/here.py` works, but `./run.sh` doesn't?

Comment: I ask about python 2.7 because there were many changes in the way string encoding was handled between versions.

Comment: @user2781994 Many *nix systems come with some flavor of Python 2 installed for use in system tooling. Even if you never installed it by hand, it may still be on your system.

Comment: `/volume1/web/python/run.sh` works fine but only in SSH.. as task, it fails

Comment: What do you mean as a task? As a cron job? As a background process?

Comment: @PatrickCollins It should be something like a cron job, it can be set only (or at least I don't know other ways) in the UI of the NAS.

Comment: Do you use a relative path anywhere in `run.sh` or `app.py`?

Comment: @PatrickCollins NO, I checked that like 1000 times

Comment: What happens if you drop `str()` from around `i.read()`? That would clear up some issues stemming from not `.encode()` or `.decode()`ing things. I can't imagine why you'd have issues in one environment but not the other. I'm almost tempted to say that your NAS has `alias python3=python` somewhere.

Comment: @PatrickCollins returns the same exception (I put it there, because sometimes it threw "bytes cannot be converted to string.." when _var a_ already had some text)
And python is not assigned to python3..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little puzzled, but here's my guess: [`open()` defaults to the shell's preferred encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and your NAS's locale is somehow set differently than your local shell's. I think that `encoding=utf-8` is the fix for your current issue.

Now, you say that doesn't work either. I'm not sure what you mean by "does not save anything" -- my guess here is that your script needs to save its output to a file, and the NAS daemon doesn't have permissions to write to that file. You don't say what the call responsible for the saving to disk actually looks like, but I believe that's a separate issue from the problem with your encoding.

Comment: The code which saves the response `f = open(os.path.join(LOCAL_DIR, "logs", filename), "a")
f.write(str(text))
f.close()`
I creates log file with successful response or with exception (which is sometimes thrown by cron job).. but usually when run as cron job, it doesn't create the file (so I assume something went wrong) :(

Comment: What's `LOCAL_DIR`? Does `LOCAL_DIR/logs` exist already? `a` mode won't create it if it doesn't, I don't think

Comment: `LOCAL_DIR` is defined in app.py (as I updated the post), `logs` exists and `a` should create the file, because it does always when run by SSH. And task is run as `root`, so it should have all the permissions to create new file.